# jQuery: Test to see if name attribute is equal to a given string

Tags: jquery

Given a list of HTML inputs, textareas, and selects, I would like to check and see if any have a name attribute equal to a given string, and if any do, to add a class to it.

For example:

```
if($('textarea, input, select').attr("name") == "this_name"){
    $(this).addClass("myClass");
}
```

I'm just not sure what I', doing wrong here, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

```
$("textarea[name='this_name'], input[name='this_name'], select[name='this_name']").addClass("myClass");
```

Look to use CSS3 selectors within jQuery

Comment: If you're going to use jsfiddle, ensure you use the correct library. This is for jQuery, not for Mootools!

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is:

```
$('textarea, input, select').filter('[name="this_name"]').addClass("myClass");
```

because your `.attr()` will look for the `name`attribute of the *first matched element* (see the [documentation on attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/))

Comment: This is slower than the below method - this will pull out all elements that are texarea, input or select, then filter!

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

$("textarea[name='this_name']").addClass("myClass");

See: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/